# constrains in odoo 12

Tags: python, odoo

I want to rais ValidationError when product_qty < 0. It prints the error but doesn't raise error and product_qty accepts negative numbers.
print : ('Product Quantity must be positive.', None)

```
class CustomEmployee(models.Model):
_name = 'employee.custom'

name = fields.Char(string=_('Employee'), required=True)
device_model = fields.Many2one('product.product', string=_('Device Model'), required=True)
product_qty = fields.Integer(string=_('Custody Quantity'))

@api.one
@api.constrains('product_qty')
def _check_product_qty(self):
    if self.product_qty < 0:
        raise ValidationError(_('Product Quantity must be positive.'))
```

Comment: Your code looks OK. Did you try to put a brakpoint in the _check_product_qty() method to see what's going on there ?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have imported odoo exceptions:

`from odoo import exceptions`

And that you are using the odoo form of raising exceptions:

`raise exceptions.ValidationError(_('Product Quantity must be positive.'))`